# What is correct way to work with hotfix branch in GitLab flow?

Tags: git, gitlab

I use [GitLab flow](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/gitlab_flow.html#environment-branches-with-gitlab-flow) environment branches in GitHub service.
I have 3 secured from direct commits branches `main` (dev branch), `staging` (pre-prod) and `production` branches.
I deployed `release-1` to production. After that I merge significant code refactoring to `main` branch. In prod I found an issue in module which I refactored in `main` branch and need to fix it in prod. I couldn't find such scenario in GitLab flow examples. So what can I do:

1. Check out `hot-fix-1` branch from `production`.
2. Make a fix in `hot-fix-1` branch.
3. Merge this fix to `staging` to test.
4. If everything OK, I merge from `staging` to `production`.

Because module is refactored in `main` branch fix should be done in a different way in `main`. So I create new branch from `main`, fix the issue and merge back to `main`. Is this correct?

Now I added `Feature2` to main branch and want to release it. When I create PR from `main` to `staging` I will get a conflict. To resolve this conflict I need to merge `staging` to `main` and resolve the conflict. But this contradicts with GitLab flow.

How would you do hot fix in production in case of significant code change in problem module in dev branch?
[image]

Comment: Which [GitLab flow](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/gitlab_flow.html) are you using? Your picture doesn't quite match any of the three I see described there. Based on the branch names I would guess you're using "Release branches with GitLab flow", however, in that flow `release` isn't a long running branch, and your hotfixes would go into `main` and then get cherry-picked into all of the release branches you wish to support.

Comment: Thank you @TTT ! I rephrased the question. Hope now it is more clear.

Answer (score 3):

> To resolve this conflict I need to merge staging to main and resolve the conflict. But this contradicts with GitLab flow.

You don't actually need to do that in order to resolve the conflict. Instead, do the merge on another temporary branch. For example, create a new branch off of `staging`, merge `main` into it, resolve the conflicts, commit the merge, and then merge that temporary branch into `staging`. When you're done you can delete that temp branch just like you would delete a feature branch after merging it into `main`.

Note I suggested starting the temp branch with `staging` and merging in `main`, rather than the other way around as you suggested. Although the end *state* will be the same either way, I tend to always start from the branch I am attempting to merge into (aka the target), so that the branch retains the same first-parent history as if you were able to merge `main` into `staging` cleanly without conflicts. This is especially helpful if you end up using a fast-forward merge of the temp branch into the target (in this case `staging`). If you were using `--no-ff` for merges (like in Git Flow), then it probably wouldn't matter which side you start the temp branch from. GitLab Flow with Environment Branches doesn't say whether or not to use `--ff` or `--no-ff`, but based on what I've read about it I think I'd prefer to use fast-forward for all merges into Env branches (all branches except `main`) whenever possible, and if you do that you'll want your temp branch to start from the target branch.

**Side Note:** I just want to point out that the [GitLab Flow](https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/topics/gitlab_flow.html) documentation starts off with a mention of (what they perceive as) the problems with Git Flow, and one of them is the complexity of separate release and hotfix branches:

> The second problem of Git flow is the complexity introduced by the hotfix and release branches. These branches can be a good idea for some organizations but are overkill for the vast majority of them. Nowadays, most organizations practice continuous delivery, which means that your default branch can be deployed. Continuous delivery removes the need for hotfix and release branches, including all the ceremony they introduce.

Although I agree with much of that paragraph, I disagree that the "complexity" introduced by `hotfix` and `release` branches is a problem. Either you need them or you don't. I can see the benefits of GitLab Flow if you don't need them, but when you do need them, the GitLab Flow way to handle hotfixes IMHO is actually more complicated than the way Git Flow handles hotfixes. My point here is that GitLab Flow seems to work best when you don't need hotfixes. Perhaps your scenario is rare, but if it starts becoming the norm, you may want to consider switching strategies.

Comment: But after you merge (ff) `temp` to `staging` you still won't be able to merge fast-forward subsequent changes from `master` to `staging`, isn't it?

Comment: @Dunken In general, for most of the merges, fast-forward probably won't be possible. (I think this is why I said I'd prefer ff "whenever possible".) However, in the specific scenario where you have conflicts and must create a temporary branch for the merge, it is always possible to fast-forward that temp branch into the target if you wish. My mention of ff in that case was only to say that if you are going to use ff to merge in the temp branch, make sure the temp branch starts from the target and merges in the source branch (rather than the other way around), to preserve first-parent history.